# Embed images into adobe InDesign template using URL

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

I want to load an image into an InDesign template using an internet URL when I import an XML.

Is this possible? Or does the image need to be stored on the local machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this possible? No. Does the image need to be stored on the local machine? Yes.